# Hyper-V VM guest can't ping any machine

Tags: hyper-v, ping, internet

So I got

Host: Hyper-v enabled machine with four NICs, only one enabled.
Network type: External

IP configuration are correct for both host and guest (getting it from the DHCP of the company network)

**The same configuration works on a machine with single NIC**

But With this other machine, with 4 NICs, there is no Internet in the guest, actually it can't ping any IP expect the host (pings host IP only, not the name)

I searched the Internet and did every solution, more than once, with no success.

Comment: Please provide details about the actual network configuration: physical NIC, virtual switch, network adapter of the VM. A statement "The same configuration works somewhere else" does not provide any kind of useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried manually configuring the NIC inside the VM?

It sounds like a mis-configured Virtual Network, have you confirmed that the correct NIC is bound to the Virtual Network Switch. I have a Dell server, that is very confusing to tell that on.